# Spotify Play Button sizing in hidden elements

Tags: button, iframe, spotify, sizing

We have some embedded Spotify play buttons in a paged quiz style wizard/carousel (using jQuery Tools -yuk- to provide the paging functionality); the issue I'm having is that because each question is on a div that is initially hidden, the content of each Spotify iframe is unable to work out which player to render (small vs large).

It would be possible to force a refresh of these iframes when the user scrolls to each panel, but this feels like a hack and a bunch of extra HTTP requests.

Has anyone had any experience with this? Any workarounds that don't require me to multiply requests to Spotify?

Thanks in advance

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team in charge of the Spotify Play Button has recently released an update that fixes this issue. You don't need to make any change in your embed code.

Here I attach some sample code, together with its jsFiddle.

In example, being this the HTML:

```html
    <button id="show-play">Show Play Button</button>
    <div id="container" style="display:none">
        <iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

you change its style CSS property:

```js
    (function() {
        var button = document.getElementById('show-play'),
            container = document.getElementById('container');

        button.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function() {
                container.style.display = 'block';
            },
            false
        );
    })();
```

You can see it in action in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4M5zE/).

Disclaimer: I'm a Spotify employee.